# Assembly - loop over strings using rep

Tags: assembly, x86

I read a book about Assembly, and it has the next code:

```
.DATA
    string1 db ’abcdfghi’,0
    strLen EQU $ - string1
    string2 db ’abcdefgh’,0
.CODE

.STARTUP
    mov AX,DS ; set up ES
    mov ES,AX ; to the data segment
    mov ECX,strLen
    mov ESI,string1
    mov EDI,string2
    cld ; forward direction
    repe cmpsb
leaves ESI pointing to g in string1 and EDI to f in string2. Therefore, adding
    dec ESI
    dec EDI
leaves ESI and EDI pointing to the last character that differs. Then we can use,  
ja str1Above
```

It is writen that we need:

```
 dec ESI
 dec EDI
```

becuase `leaves ESI pointing to g in string1 and EDI to f in string2.`

But why? When we arrive to 'f' in `ESI`, and 'e' in `EDI`, the `repe` condition is not fulfill, and for that we would exit the loop, where 'f' is in `ESI`, and 'e' is in `EDI`. Why It say that we continue to scan the strings one more time?

Answer (score 1):

That's the way repe works:

1. ecx = 0 or Zeroflag = 0 --> out
2. dec ecx
3. do command
4. increase (or decrease) esi and edi.
5. back to 1.

So esi and edi point to address + 1 (or - 1 in case of backwards direction).

Comment: repe also check if esi=edi, no? In our case, It exit from the loop because esi<>edi, and not because ecx=0.

Comment: Sure - missed that, thanks. The point was, that the exit condition is at the beginning. That's why you need to adjust the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If the direction flag `DF` is clear in the `EFLAGS` register, ESI and EDI are incremented *after* the comparison **exits**. So the `dec` instructions are compensating for this. I think. The `rep` string instructions are a bit of a hangover from the 8086 'CISC' days.